# I get WebException timeout when I use webclient.DownloadFile after webclient.ResponseHeaders

Tags: c#, webclient, response-headers, webexception

I am trying to create my own download manger.
When a link is added to the download manger I use a webclient to get it's information from the server. Like so

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.OpenRead(link);
string filename = webClient.ResponseHeaders["Content-Disposition"];
```

After that I download the file using DownloadFile

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
if (!fileInfo.Exists)
{
    webClient.DownloadFile(link, path);
}
```

When I do it like this. I get a WebException timeout.
However, when I remove the webClient.ResponseHeaders part. It never get the timeout exception.
I really need to read the Content-Disposition because some of the links don't have the name of the file on them.
I even tried using a different webclient for downloading and getting it's info but I got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by finding another way to get the files info.

```
string Name = "";
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Link);
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

for(int i=0; i < myHttpWebResponse.Headers.Count; i++)
{
    if (myHttpWebResponse.Headers.Keys[i] == "Content-Disposition")
    {
        Name = myHttpWebResponse.Headers[i];
    }
}
myHttpWebResponse.Close();
```